# Replace CSS classes everywhere when building for production (css, html / twig, javascript)

Tags: css, obfuscation, bem

I consider using the **[BEM](http://getbem.com/introduction/)** naming convention in my next project but I'm kind of worried about performances because of the long class names.

Take for example (source is [here](https://seesparkbox.com/foundry/bem_by_example)):

```html
<figure class="photo">
  <img class="photo__img photo__img--framed" src="me.jpg">
  <figcaption class="photo__caption photo__caption--large">Look at me!</figcaption>
</figure>
```

In a complex project with dozens of sass files the difference can become non-negligible.

I'm working with Symfony 4 and I wonder if there is an elegant way to replace all css classes in both the css output AND twig templates with lightweight names like `a`, `b`, `c`, `...`, `aa`, `ab`, etc.

The JavaScript output may also be a consideration because it may add css classes dynamically to certain elements.

For the css part, I think that a Webpack plugin doing global replacements on the final output could be enough.

For the JavaScript, I think it's almost impossible to get it right because the classes names could be generated dynamically (`var className = "--is-" + this.state;`), or even worse, be returned from the server or any other fancy way you can imagine.

So I thought about adding a prefix to classes that should not be replaced. Like starting them with `_`.

But the html part (or should I say the `twig` part) is harder to solve because it can't be ignored like the Javascript part and there is no transformation between the code written in development and the code used in production.

I guess that twig compiles everything into php when the cache is built, so maybe there is something to do using compilation hooks or something is that area.

Do you know any tools that does this kind of thing?

How the big sites deal with this? 
For example, if I open the inspector in a Google service I see things like this:

```html
<button class="GBTG6V-f-a GBTG6V-f-l GBTG6V-f-p GBTG6V-f-g" [...]>
```

Doesn't look very human friendly to me.

Thanks for your insights.

Comment: It seems unlikely that your performance boost from this is going to be substantial enough to be worth it. My guess is that Google uses some sort of auto minification, similar to what Cloudflare provides. That doesn't work if you're dynamically generating classnames in JS. I guess if you really wanted to do it, you'd want to create a standalone JS tool with a set of rules that you could call to translate state "framed" to "a", and then perform the same translation on your CSS and HTML prior to deployment. Is this worth saving a few KB of initial load when the CSS is probably cached anyway?

Comment: The problem with BEM is that you repeat your selectors a lot. I can't say for sure because I didn't use it yet, but I would not be surprised of a huge impact on the size if used intensively. But I may be overreacting. But even then, does it worth it? If I have to develop the whole thing myself for myself, probably not. If I develop it to share, maybe. But if someone already did something similar there is no point in reinventing the wheel. Maybe the best thing to do is to develop a project with BEM, do a quick dirty script to replace the classes, compare and see if it worth it.

Comment: Personally I don't believe in ditching the cascading features of CSS to the extent that BEM does. I write everything in SCSS with the starting point of what colors, fonts and other basic attributes are going to be common in a project? I make a base class for each of those. Then it's easy to add them as a standalone class. For complex things, I do inheritance from those using `@extend` and `@include` mixins where possible. The blocks of SCSS are very readable since each starts with `@extend`s and then cascades are nested. Closer to the Bootstrap method of making a simple class for everything.

Comment: In the case that could help, I personally use a [compliant-to-bem variant](https://paleo.casa/pleasant-bem.html) without these repetitions.

Comment: _“but I would not be surprised of a huge impact on the size if used intensively”_ - what “size” are we talking about? The mere text content of the resource itself, that has to be send over the net? That should become absolutely negligible, once you apply gzip or deflate compression.

Comment: Yes the text of css files and html templates.. But yeah, after putting it into perspective I realize that I may have overthought this one a bit. That's why I posted a question, it helps to have an external point of view before diving in (maybe) a bad direction. So I think that I'll stick to what I said in my previous comment. I'll do my next project with BEM in mind, see if I like it and look again at these micro-optimizations "problems" at the end if there is matter to worry. Thanks to all of you for your advices.